# Get relationships from API call to Drupal

Tags: angular, drupal-8, json-api

I'm  trying to set up Drupal as a headless CMS to serve data up to an Angular app using [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org). I'm able to get a response object from my GET requests, but the response data doesn't include any of the reference field types (e.g. images or tags). Instead, it returns an object of relationships that includes the reference field types.

example response object:

```
"data": {
  "type": "node--release",
  "id": "21bff999-241d-4807-bd00-4af7f5a767ff",
  "attributes": {
    "nid": 11,
    "uuid": "21bff999-241d-4807-bd00-4af7f5a767ff",
    "vid": 11,
    "title": "Example title",
    "created": 1506621775,
    "changed": 1506621912,
    "revision_timestamp": 1506621912,
    "revision_log": null,
    "path": null,
    "field_artist": "Band name",
    "field_description": {
      "value": "<p>Album description</p>\r\n",
      "format": "basic_html"
    },
    "field_title": "Album name",
  },
  "relationships": {
    "field_image_large": {
      "data": {
        "type": "file--file",
        "id": "83d45147-1339-45a0-ae8e-fc662575d77b",
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost/error-records/jsonapi/node/release/21bff999-241d-4807-bd00-4af7f5a767ff/relationships/field_image_large",
        "related": "http://localhost/error-records/jsonapi/node/release/21bff999-241d-4807-bd00-4af7f5a767ff/field_image_large"
      }
    },
  },
}
```

I want to display the image that was uploaded to "field_image_large", but none of the links (neither self nor related) direct to where the image is stored. Further, when I make an API call to either of them, the returned results don't provide a link to where the image is stored either.

Answer (score 1):

You could do
`GET /jsonapi/node/release/{resourceID}?include=field_image_large`
And in `included[0].links` you will find an image path.
By the way, with a bunch of modules, you could even get responsive images. One of them is [Consumer Image Styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/consumer_image_styles). More information about it you could find out in the mentioned link.